# What is the meaning of |⋯| notation for an index subset?

Tags: matrices, notation, average, clustering

I am currently working on a research project. In the attached image what does the capital $|I|$ and $|J|$ mean ? 
[image: scan of a book]

Comment: Number of elements in this context.

Comment: In the paragraph above the notation, you have "where $I$ is the set of rows in the bicluster, and $J$ is the set of columns."  What more do you want?

Comment: yes at first i thought it was the number of total cols or rows in a set but the | | were confusing me. so it means that if a matrix have 10 rows and 5 cols so I = 10 and J = 5 ? am i right ?

Comment: No, $|I|=10$ and $|J|=5$, and $I=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, $J=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, $| I |$ stands for the number of rows in the bicluster and similarly, $| J | = $ number of columns. More generally, the notation $|A|$ (usually) means the number of elements in a set $A$.

Comment: cleared my confusion !